# After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS my Firewire card does not work

Tags: 18.04, firewire

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and then did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04LTS and a new SSD.
I have a Unibrain FireBoard PCI-32Bit 3 x FireWire Ports Red installed with a Lacie d2 Quadra external storage box attached which I can no longer see.
All else appears to be working.
I have googled for fix but cannot find anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Thanks - Dave

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching and testing (Kdenlive would not recognise my miniDV camera connected via firewire but dvgrab worked!) I finally found the fix - I needed to load the firewire-sbp2 module

```
sudo modprobe-sbp2
```

thanks to websites

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire

https://opensource.com/article/18/5/how-load-or-unload-linux-kernel-module

Comment: sudo modprobe firewire-sbp2

Comment: Hi Simo - thanks for correction - in the joy of getting my firewire storage working I did not proof read my entry!

Comment: ;-) lucky you .. I'm still struggling ! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138965/ubuntu-18-04-and-firewire-device

Comment: dvgrab worked for me, but I don't know enough about linux to debug - sorry