# ubuntu 18.04 and firewire device

Tags: video, video-editor, firewire

There is only old documentation /threads regarding ubuntu and firewire device.
Actually I want tp capture videos form my old Sony camera using minDV format.

Using Kdenlive or dvgrab, my device never get recognised.

I applied these commands :

```
sudo modprobe  firewire-core 
sudo modprobe firewire-sbp2
```

Still I'm not able to get anything...

I can see loaded module by typing `lsmod | grep -E -i "firewire"`

and I'm able to see my pci card using `lspci | grep -E -i "firewire"`

using dvgrab, I get "no camera exists" message.

Any help will be very welcome

I can read this message related to firewire when displaying log with `journalctl`:

> avril 29 20:37:13 magnific-bob kernel: firewire_core 0000:09:01.0: rediscovered device fw0

And the output from @waltinator (complex) command :

```
uid=1000(simon) gid=1000(simon) groupes=1000(simon),4(adm),6(disk),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
      412      0 crw-------   1 root     root     242,   0 avril 29 20:26 /dev/fw0
             fonctionnalités: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             ressources: mémoire:fea00000-feafffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                produit: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                fabriquant: Ricoh Co Ltd
--
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=32 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                ressources: irq:16 mémoire:feaff800-feafffff
           *-generic:0
09:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: Unplug the camera. Replug the camera. In a terminal window, type `journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` to see log messages.

Comment: @waltinator : thanks. I've updated my first message

Comment: Please show us the results of these commands, with the camera plugged in: `id;find /dev/ -name fw0 -ls 2>/dev/null;sudo lshw | grep -A2 -B2 -i fire;lspci | grep -E -i "firewire"`.

Comment: @waltinator : nic one-line command ! see my edit ! And thanks again.

Comment: @waltinator or someone else : any idea ?